# How to restrict user from entering number in to an input field with type as text?

Tags: javascript, html

How to disable the user from entering a number in to input field . When we use type as number we are restricted from entering text in to the input .The same way how to achieve the vice versa . Someone help i need this to complete my assignment.

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

Comment: yeah  you are right . i have changed it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen to  `keydown`, and if the key pressed is a number, just call `event.preventDefault()` on the keyboard event.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if((/\d/g).test(event.key)) event.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `input` event listener to the input which gets the input's value, replaces every numeric character (with [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)), then assigns the result back to the input's value:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\D]/g,'')
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

Comment: How you enter `+`, `-`. `e` and `.` then?

Comment: I was also mistaken, OP wants the opposite.

Comment: It's not as easy as this, though. This wrecks cursor position when trying to enter a number in any position other than the end of the value.

Comment: `keydown` and `event.preventDefault` seems a more viable approach with less problems to solve.

Comment: ok i just tried to console.log the this.value and it returned undefined.. It doesnot work . this.value is not accesible from here.

Comment: @NoushadM How is it not? Have you tried logging it inside the `input` event listener?

Comment: @NoushadM You need to use a regular `function`, not an arrow function. otherwise   `this`will be `window`, and `window.value` is `undefined`.

Comment: ohh wait let me try with the regular function now .. and yes i had used input event only

Comment: Nice It worked well .. i had been using arrow function . Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 line function to prevent any number in the `input` with help of regular expression

> But it is not recommended to use inline function , here is provided only to tell about a different approach

[See here to know more about regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```html
<input type="text" name="name" oninput=" this.value = this.value.replace(/[0-9]/g,'')" />
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to use `pattern` with regex:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" pattern="\D" />
```

`\D` will reject all digits

Comment: I can enter numbers into your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, but if your are using this in a form, and try to submit it, you can't because you don't match the pattern.

Comment: good suggestion but i can still enter a numeric value. I think its easier to get this done in react with onchange .

Comment: totally wrong what question asked.